# ES Chromecast Player no longer works for ES File Explorer

Tags: chromecast, es-file-explorer

The brilliant ES File Explorer has been my go-to app for quite some time now. I particularly liked using it for Chromecast. However the ES Chromecast Player has recently stopped working for me.

When I select ES Chromecast Player the screen goes black and I no longer get the dialog popping up that allows me to select the device to cast to.

I've tried uninstalling both the ES File Explorer and ES Chromecast Player apps and then re-installing them, but the problem still persists.

Any idea what the issue might be, or things I might try to fix the issue? All other apps are still able to cast to my Chromecast device.

My device is a Sony Xperia Z1 Compact. The device is not rooted or anything like that.

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: ES File Explorer (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the app's latest update, and the developer has to fix that. Other users have got this issue too. ([Play store reviews](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.chromecast&reviewId=Z3A6QU9xcFRPR0pYYUppNkl6OWpUQVZuakRianJ5dU9VdkdOaGx2aVFEYjJlRW8tYnkwRC1xb1JrNzNjNk9MSEJxckJtSFVLXzJhQ3B2SVc1djlqTzhLWjFN&hl=en))

Comment: Interesting, when I originally encountered the issue no-one else was complaining via reviews and I found old posts from way back by people with the same issue so I figured it was user device / setup related. Thanks for prompting me to look at the user reviews again.

Comment: The addon ES Chromecast seems to have been removed from Google play. I also failed to install it from APK for Android 9.0. Any idea how to make it working?